# How to fix "TypeError: an integer is required (got type IntVar)" in mysql python

Tags: python, tkinter, pymysql

I'm trying to insert Date in my database table. but I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SchoolApp\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/SchoolApp/Python/register only.py", line 45, in register
    self.entry_birthday = datetime.datetime(self.birth_day)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type IntVar)
```

I converted my variable `self.get_birthday` to `int(self.get_birthday)` but it's still an error.

Here's my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import pymysql
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import datetime

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        master.title("Thesis")

        self.register_button = Button(master, text="Register", command=self.register)
        self.register_button.pack()

        self.db = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost",user = "root",passwd = "",db = "database")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.QueryResident = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS residence (BIRTH_DATE date, AGE varchar(255)not null)"
        self.cursor.execute(self.QueryResident)

    def registered(self,birth_day):
        self.get_birth_day =self.birth_day.get()

        if (self.get_birth_day == ""):
                messagebox.showerror("Error!","Please complete the required field")
        else:
            self.cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO residence (BIRTH_DATE) VALUES(%s)",(self.get_birth_day))

            self.db.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo("Success!","Registration successful")

        self.cursor.close()
        self.db.close()


    def register(self):
        self.master_register = Toplevel()

        self.birth_day = IntVar()

        self.label_birthday = Label(self.master_register, text = "Birth Day")
        self.label_birthday.pack()
        self.entry_birthday = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.birth_day)
        self.entry_birthday = datetime.datetime(self.birth_day)
        self.entry_birthday.pack()
        self.button_submit = Button(self.master_register, text = "Submit", command = lambda: self.registered(self.birth_day))
        self.button_submit.pack()
```

My expected output is the inputted date get will store to a database in any date format and I will compute the age based on the given birth day.

Comment: What error do you get with the code as it is here exactly? It seems you changed the code since you last got the described error

Comment: Hi sir, I Forgot to put my full traceback error. I've done the editing now.

Comment: Would be nice if you can include a running code that reproduces the error with imports and classes. That said you define the name self.entry_birthday as a datetime object and then try to pack it. This is not possible. I think you want to convert self.birthday to a datetime object instead. By the way what format must be self.birthday? `datetime.datetime` can take 3 arguments for year, month, day, for example `datetime.datetime(1995, 12, 15)`

Comment: Hi sir @BrunoVermeulen, I edited the code and also put the import modules. I didn't specify the format of my self.birthday. So I will have 3 entries? like, `birth_year` `birth_day` and `birth_month`? and put it to datetime.datetime(birth_year, birth_day, birth_month)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here some modifications to hopefully help you a little further. Basically you need to define how the date needs to be entered (so I choose a format `yyyymmdd`). Also best to enter as a StringVar. Then in the method registered parse the `yyyymmdd` into a datetime object, which you then can put into your database.

Using 'try-except' any date in the wrong format will not be accepted.

Code

```
import tkinter as tk
import pymysql
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import datetime

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        master.title("Thesis")

        self.register_button = Button(master, text="Register", command=self.register)
        self.register_button.pack()

        self.db = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost",user = "root",passwd = "",db = "database")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.QueryResident = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS residence (BIRTH_DATE date, AGE varchar(255)not null)"
        self.cursor.execute(self.QueryResident)

    def registered(self,birth_day):

        birthday = self.birth_day.get()
        try:
            _year = int(birthday[0:4])
            _month = int(birthday[4:6])
            _day = int(birthday[6:8])

            birthday = datetime.datetime(_year, _month, _day)
            print(birthday)  # for debugging purpose you can remove

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            birthday = ""

        if (birthday == ""):
                messagebox.showerror("Error!","Please complete the required field")

        else:
            sql_string = "INSERT INTO residence (BIRTH_DATE) VALUES(%s)"
            print(sql_string) # for debugging purpose you can remove
            self.cursor.execute (sql_string,(birthday))

            self.db.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo("Success!","Registration successful")

        self.cursor.close()
        self.db.close()

    def register(self):
        self.master_register = Toplevel()

        self.birth_day = StringVar()

        self.label_birthday = Label(self.master_register, text = "Birth Day [yyyymmdd]")
        self.label_birthday.pack()
        self.entry_birthday = Entry(self.master_register, textvariable = self.birth_day)
        self.entry_birthday.pack()
        self.button_submit = Button(self.master_register, text = "Submit", command = lambda: self.registered(self.birth_day))
        self.button_submit.pack()

root = Tk()
Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn't a little help! It's the biggest help I've received this day. Thank you so much. What I'm doing next is to put a separator '/' to year, month and day like this yyyy/mm/dd.  Again, thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer helped you to get further, please can you vote this as `answered`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`self.birth_day` is an *object*, not an integer. Since it is an `IntVar`, you need to call the `get` method to retrieve the value.

```
datetime.datetime(self.birth_day.get())
```

Comment: I got it, sir, Thank you so much! You guys were a big help. Thank You!

Comment: As far as I am concerned `self.entry_birthday` should never be a `datetime` object. How can you pack this?

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen: I don't understand your comment. The point isn't what `self.entry_birthday` is or isn't, the question was about why `datetime.datetime` was throwing the error. I'll remove the assignment from the example to avoid confusion.

Comment: You are correct that this would solves the immediate question, however the  original code has several other flaws that I tried to correct as well in my answer. Ultimately it was wrong to change a Entry object to a datetime object...